# How can we achieve last month record in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, date-arithmetic

I am new to oracle and I am writing a query where I have to fetch last month
My query:

```
 select to_char(sysdate,'MON') from dual
```

But it is giving me 

AUG which is current month.

 I want the output as JUL which is last month

How can we achieve last month record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select to_char(ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, -1),'MON') from dual 

--Move ahead one month: 
ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, 1);

--Move backward 1 month: 
ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, -1);
```

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-jan/o12plsql-1408561.html

> Oracle Database offers several built-in functions for shifting a date
>   by the requested amount or finding a date:

```
 ADD_MONTHS—adds the specified number of months to or subtracts it from a date (or a timestamp) 
NEXT_DAY—returns the date of the first weekday named in the call to the function 
LAST_DAY—returns the date of the last day of the month of the specified date
```